How do I get a combobox to only list the people in my sharepoint list and not my entire company?
So I have a SharePoint list called PeopleList that has two columns: Names (a Person column) and Department (a Text column).
In PowerApps, I am using a ComboBox so that I can select the people from PeopleList. However, when I use either of these two codes:
Items = Choices([@PeopleList].Names)

or
Items = PeopleList.Names

The dropdown gives an entire table of EVERYONE in my company, not the names found in my SharePoint list. How do I make it so that it only gives the table from my list?

If PeopleList is the name of SharePoint list and items property of dropdown is linked with it then there is no way it can show users from your organization, so kindly share the screen shot of you app, what connections you made for it? dropdown in inside gallery or form or just on the screen? More information will help to understand the issue.

Your code is populating the dropdown correctly because the formulas mentioned above will give you the source data of your field, which is @Everyone.
To get the names found in my SharePoint list you can use the Distinct function with a combination of ForAll:
ForAll(Distinct(PeopleList, Names), ThisRecord.Value.DisplayName)

Distinct will get you all the distinct people and ForAll will get you the Names of each record

Can you clarify? Because the name of the sharepoint list is PeopleList. So would the code be ForAll(Distinct(PeopleList, PeopleList), Names)? If so it doesn't work.

Yes it will be ForAll(Distinct(, ), )

Can you clarify this part   ?
With my current formula it returns a table of all the employees, which is what I need. Are you suggesting that I pick a column from that table and plug it into your formula?
Like this: ForAll(Distinct(PeopleList, Names), DisplayName) ?
If so, it doesn't recognize "DisplayName"

Little miss from my side, I have updated the answer with your correct parameters, it should work now?

THAT WORKED THANK YOU! I dropped the DisplayName since I wanted a table return
